# Getting audio sample back from speech recognition module

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, text-to-speech

I am using Speech Recognition module in python to convert speech to text and spacy to extract some words from text . Can I get the audio sample or duration during which a certain word was spoken ?

for example I have an audio file . I get word 'orange' in text . I want to obtain the duration during which this specific word was spoken in audio file for example 3:10 to 3:12 , word orange was spoken

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

i think we should take that into consideration while training a model.
i know of no open source model that does that even thou it looks very simple
if some one have any names share them please.
you still can use google or azure api for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).